# Explanation of Puppet code

Tags: puppet

Here is my Puppet code:

```
  file { 'copy_files':
     path => "/data/files",
     source => "puppet:///modules/mymodule/repo",
     recurse => true;
  }
  file {'chmod_script':
     path => "/data/files/inner_folder/script",
     ensure => 'present',
     mode => "+x"
  }
```

What i want is to copy my folder ('repo') and then make one script executable. However with the above code, everything inside my script gets erased (script is just empty file). Without that addition resource ('chmod_script') file's content is as expected(not erased). So am i doing something wrong here? I thought it might be because 2nd resource('chmod_Script') is executed earlier but docs says "Puppet applies resources in the order they’re declared in their manifest.". So can someone explain me how it should look like?

**EDIT**
I've decide to use this script:

```
  file { 'copy_files':
     path => "/data/files",
     source => "puppet:///modules/mymodule/repo",
     recurse => true;
  }
  file {'chmod_script':
     path => "/data/files/inner_folder/script",
     source => "puppet:///modules/mymodule/repo/inner_folder/script",
     ensure => 'present',
     mode => "+x"
  }
```

So while updating mode, i'm copying content once more.

Comment: If the second resource was executed first, then logically the script would not be empty. Anyway, path of least resistance here is for the script to be executable in the source.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yeah i thought about making it executable in the source. But wondered why my solution doesnt work as expected. Also, if 2nd resource was executed first then it would just create empty, executable file (just like it happens in my case), or am i wrong?

Comment: Great question. I figured it out and answered below @peterSchiza.

Comment: @peterSchiza Yes it would create an empty executable file that would then be replaced by the script with content from the first resource. Therefore, your second resource cannot be executing first.

Comment: @peterSchiza It would be great for the archives if you gave this question a better heading than "Explanation of Puppet Code".

Comment: @MattSchuchard this actually has nothing to do with manifest ordering; you could order this any way you like in the manifest or using before/require and still get the same result. It is, rather, about the fact that the catalog gets compiled on the master, and then at apply time the catalog then gets patched to include a resource for each file in the remote dir - minus any files that overlap with files already in the catalog!  I actually tested it in a debugger, see my answer below.

Comment: @AlexHarvey i was not talking about manifest ordering and I was also explaining why his theory about this occurring because the second resource executes first is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be running into an undocumented behaviour.

When you run `puppet agent -t`, the Puppet Agent requests that the Puppet Master compile a catalog and, all things being equal, since you asked about the ordering, it orders everything according to how you have written it in the manifest (assuming you have Puppet 4 or a version of Puppet 3 that is more recent than early 2014).

Next, if you asked Puppet via `recurse` to mirror a remote directory, Puppet actually patches the compiled catalog and adds a resource for every file in the remote directory to it. (And Puppet continues to honour the manifest ordering.)

But here's the catch. Duplicate resources are not allowed, so Puppet makes a decision about which one to keep if the compiled catalog already contains a file resource that overlaps with a file that would be added via `recurse`. If the catalog already contains a file resource via a specific declaration, the one already in the catalog wins.

So, in your case, Puppet doesn't know anything at all about the remote content of 
`inner_folder/script`, and you haven't specified any content, so Puppet just creates an empty file.

(Also, have a look at the discussion in [Bug 2296](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/file.html#file-attribute-source_permissions) to understand the behaviour in other related edge-cases.)

I agree with Matt Schuchard that the best thing to do here, given your requirement, is just to set the executable flag (`+x`) in the remote directory.

In addition, however, you will also need to use `source_permissions => use` ([doc](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/file.html#file-attribute-source_permissions)):

```
  file { 'copy_files':
     path => "/data/files",
     source => "puppet:///modules/mymodule/repo",
     source_permissions => use,
     recurse => true,
  }
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work. I've changed mode of that file (+x) on remote but it doesnt have it after i run puppet script on client... Any ideas how can it be done? Or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @peterSchiza, you are not doing it wrong. I just tested it and, sadly, as you say, it doesn't work. That leaves us only with bad options here, and I updated the post. My recommendation, actually, is not to use `recurse => true` but find another way to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've decide to use another approach and included it in my first post(don't really know if its better than yours tho). Also, how copying directory can be done without using  `recurse => true` ?

Comment: Oh good idea. Yes, I think that's the best answer. You should really make that an "answer" rather than adding it to the question. That way we can mark the question as resolved.

Comment: @peterSchiza I just discovered a better way and I updated the answer: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/file.html#file-attribute-source_permissions

Comment: Thanks. Yea, your answer seems the best.